# Why is the collection in Typescript update twice in firebase?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic4

```
 // round page
  newRound() {
    console.log('new round ', this.round);
    this.you.score = +this.score;
    this.round++;
    console.log('THE PLAYERS -> ', this.players);
    this.afStore.collection('matches').doc(this.gameRoom).collection('match').doc(`${this.round}`).set({players: this.players, round: this.round}).then(() => {
      console.log('UPDATED GAME');
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/events/tab2/' + this.gameRoom]);
  }
 // Tab page that goes to the round page
// NOTE: this is for the next page, round 1,2,3,4 etc...
  theRound() {
    this.newRound++;
    console.log('this is the new round ', this.newRound);
    this.afStore.collection('matches').doc(this.gameRoom).collection('match').doc(`${this.newRound}`).set({players: this.players, round: this.newRound});
    this.afStore.collection('matches').doc(this.gameRoom).collection('match').doc(`${this.newRound}`).valueChanges().subscribe((v: any) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/events/tab2/' + this.gameRoom + '/' + v.round]);
      console.log('data returned from firebase ', v);
    });
  }
```

Hi everyone! I've got a problem. I'm trying to update a specific collection in firebase but it creates the collection but doesn't update the "score" once I've pressed in a value in the round page. Also it creates a second collection with the updated score. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are u updating score

Comment: I'm updating it via ionic ion-input where the NgModel is score ( this.score ).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you update your document with `set()` and the firebase documentation says:

> If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document

But before you are updating, you do an increment on `this.newRound`, thus your document is an increment higher and firebase creates a new one.

Comment: I kinda understand what you're getting at. What do you recommend so that it updates only the single document and not create a new one?

Comment: I am not the best data model designer especially not in document based databases and it also depends on what you are trying to reach. I can have a look, if you post your database schema.

Comment: But @Peter Haddad was also right. Where is the score in your db query?

Comment: the score is included in the ```this.player``` array. How do I post my database schema?